# Why didn't Orochimaru use the Edo-tensei in the Konoha Arc?

Tags: naruto

Didn't orochimaru know the edo-tensei jutsu? Why did he use the hidden sound and sand. Couldn't he have just summoned the third raikage and wrecked everyone?

Comment: edo tensei is a forbidden technique and it is not something you can do coz you want to do, you need a lot of preparation. And though tobirama developed the technique it was not perfect and orichimaru was still practicing to make it perfect,and as you might know, you need DNA of the person you gonna summon

Comment: I know, but he had so much DNA and its not like he wasn't already wanted. Having so many subjects and performing experiments on them is also forbidden, but Orochimaru still did it.

Comment: Read [this](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Summoning:_Impure_World_Reincarnation), where you can read some flaws of edo tensei that orichimaru was practicing which was perfected by kabuto later

Comment: mhmk thx, didn't know that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Orochimaru was not perfect at using edo-tensei .He was only able to call third kazekage that too failed.So I think he preferred not using edo-tensei.

Even kabuto took a lot of time after Orochimaru's death to perfect in using it.